# VS 2010 Build Settings - "Release" build not included in drop-down

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have inherited an mvc3 class library project. I want to build a release cut of this library but the only thing that is available in the drop down is Active(Debug) per VS2010 Pro.

[image]

How can I create a release build?

UPDATE:

If I select Build -> Configuration Manager -> New(Reelase) I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the option to create new solution configurations.

Comment: Well, unchecking the create new version worked but for some reason when building it's not generating release bits.  Nothing in the specified release output path: bin\Release.

Comment: Ah, found it...had to pop open the hood but noticed a custom import in the project file....<Import Project="$(RootDir)Build\Targets\CustomCompany.Compile.targets" />

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Build > Configuration Manager** and select "New" in the **Active solution configuration** drop down.